# MsXml6 failing to link properly

Tags: visual-c++, msxml

Hello I am trying to use msxml and I am getting a linker (VS 2012) error and can't figure out why.

My class file has the following header declaration:

```
#include <MsXml6.h>

class Foo
{
   ....
   private:
   static IXMLDOMDocument* document;
};
```

I then reference the document with the following (which gives the link error):

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DOMDocument60, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IXMLDOMDocument, (void**)&document);
```

I have the project setup to link against msxml6.lib. The logs are as follows:

```
Searching C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x64\msxml6.lib:
1>        Found IID_IXMLDOMDocument
1>          Referenced in Foo.obj
1>          Loaded msxml6.lib(msxml6_i.obj)

...

1>Foo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct IXMLDOMDocument * Foo::document" (?document@Foo@@0PEAUIXMLDOMDocument@@EA)
1>Some.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Is there something important I am missing? Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I forgot to declare the document variable in the source file.