# MSXML6.lib import doesn't seem to be working properly. CODE BLOCKS, MSXML2.h?

Tags: c++, msxml6

On a 64 bit system, Windows 10, using `CODEBLOCKS` with the `MingW/GCC` compiler. I need to use the 
`MSXML6.lib` library and include the `msxml6.h` header.

The library is included with a current Windows SDK (which I have installed).

I have the appropriate linker path set up in CODE BLOCKS.

The problem is my `#include <msxml6.h>` directive does not work. The only header files the compiler finds are:

`<msxml.h>`, `<msxml2.h>`, `<msxml2did.h>`, and `<msxmldid.h>`.

Internet and SE/SO search of my problem turns up this:
[MsXml6 failing to link properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749881/msxml6-failing-to-link-properly)

Not quite what I'm looking for.

Tried the CODE BLOCKS forum. Perusing there, they are not all to welcoming of library and linker questions. This is ok, that's their rules, but not really all that helpful.

Anyone seen anything like this before? Is there someplace I can go to get the right header file for that library? For some reason, the library is there but header is missing from the SDK.

Comment: That's a liability of depending on MinGW, they did not manage to reverse-engineer it (yet).  These open source projects progress by taking contributions from programmers that have a need to fill, you're it right now.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Just checked and there's a new version of the compiler in the past couple weeks. Lucky me! I don't have time to wait or get involved in extra projects right now. I might have to figure out something else.

Comment: Throw that in an answer and I’ll check it for you if you’d like.

Comment: ...and thanks for teaching me something I didn't know. I appreciate it. That doesn't get said enough around the forum, I think. I posted on SorceForge to see if they will include a header with the next update or if there is something I can do to get my hands on the header to send to them for the next one.